# How to find "if Q then S" in this classic CSL derivation

Tags: logic

Here's the problem: I have to derive `Q>S` from:

1. `(P^Q^R)>S`
2. `(~P^Q^~R)>S`

I'm not allowed to use any derived rules or replacement rules (De Morgan's, implication, Modus Tolluns etc), only classic logic rules. I have tried everything I can think of and still cannot manage to get to the answer I need.

Comment: Interesting, but not [exactly] SO-material... I do want to see where it goes though ;-) A suspect a "homework" tag is appropriate at the very least?

Comment: done, sorry, I didn't know I should do that! I wasn't sure if this was the place to post questions about CSL, but I'm a little desperate and hoping some capable person can save me.

Comment: It seems so obvious that what you have is `( (P^~P) ^ Q ^ (R^~R) ) > S` and of course the "P or Not-P" is simply eliminated, but sorry, I can no longer recall the formal steps to get there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical logic, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you cannot prove it is because it is *not true*.

Consider:

```
IF P and Q are true and R and S are false, 

THEN:      < T   T    F     F >
        1. ( P & Q &  R) -> S  is true     ( because "(False) -> False" is valid )
 and    2. (~P & Q & ~R) -> S  is true     ( also because "(False) -> False" )

BUT:             Q       -> S  is NOT true ( because "True -> False" is invalid )
```

Therefore it cannot be possible to (validly) derive Q->S from your statements 1 and 2, even if you could use all of the derived rules, replacement, etc.

Pretty hard to prove something that's not true.  (In logic anyway :)